# add a rule to syntax-propertize-rules

Tags: hooks, syntax-highlighting, syntax, syntax-table, perl

I have an issue outlined [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28701/modify-syntax-table-for-strings-in-perl-modes) that I was able to find a partial solution for. The problem involved changing `perl-modes` syntax table. One of the commenters pointed me to the function `syntax-propertize-function`. Within it, there is macro called `syntax-propertize-rules` and I was able to add the following code snippet to it.

```
      ("\\('\\)[bh]" (1 "."))
```

this fixed the syntax problem I was having. However this is a change I made to the source `perl-mode.el`. What I need is some way to add this rule to `syntax-propertize-rules` from within my .emacs file. I have already tried

```
(defun my/perl-syntax-propertize-function ()
    ("\\('\\)[bh]" (1 ".")))

(add-hook 'perl-mode-hook
          (lambda () (add-function :after (symbol-function 'syntax-propertize-rules) #'my/perl-syntax-propertize-function)))
```

But this does not work. What is the correct way to make this change?

Comment: Why are you patching the macro code? Can't you just provide a list of rules as as argument to the macro? (Apologies if the question is silly; I haven't tried to understand the code.)

Comment: @Drew the macro is already defined in perl-mode.el. How can I provide arguments to it after the fact? I am very new to Emacs Lisp.

Comment: I see. Hopefully someone else here will provide you with a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you can't do it "right".
But you can do the following:

```
(defalias 'my/perl-syntax-propertize-function
  (syntax-propertize-rules ("\\('\\)[bh]" (1 "."))))

(add-hook 'perl-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-function :before (local 'syntax-propertize-function)
                          #'my/perl-syntax-propertize-function)))
```

AFAIK the main problem with the above is that it will misfire when `'b` is not the beginning of a binary constant but the end of a string followed by `b`.  Fixing this would be a lot more ugly, because you'd then need to know if you're already within a string, and to know this, you'd need to apply your rule *at the same time* as perl-mode's normal rules rather `:after` or `:before`.

Comment: I changed the regex to    ("\\('\\)b[01]+[[:space:]]*\\([,;\\)\\}]\\|$\\)" (1 "."))
so hopefully it will be more robust. still not as robust as checking if you are in a string though. Thanks for your answer!